# Javascript Observable collection count

Tags: javascript, silverlight

I'm, accessing Silverlight ObservableCollection count in javascript, but I get the following error.,

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Windows.Hosting.ScriptingInterface.GetScriptParamValueForType(ScriptParam scriptParam, Type desiredType)
   at System.Windows.Hosting.ScriptingInterface.ConvertFromScriptParams(Type[] desiredTypes, ScriptParam[] args)
   at System.Windows.Browser.ManagedObjectInfo.ListIndexerMember.Invoke(ManagedObject obj, InvokeType invokeType, ScriptParam[] args)
   at System.Windows.Browser.ManagedObjectInfo.Invoke(ManagedObject obj, InvokeType invokeType, String memberName, ScriptParam[] args)
   at System.Windows.Hosting.ManagedHost.InvokeScriptableMember(IntPtr pHandle, Int32 nMemberID, Int32 nInvokeType, Int32 nArgCount, ScriptParam[] pArgs, ScriptParam& pResult, ExceptionInfo& pExcepInfo)
```

I'm using following code, where children is a observablecollection of custom object.,

```
            reg.OnDropping = function (sender, args) {
                if (args.toItem.Children.Count > 0) {
                    args.cancel = true;
                }
                else {
                    args.cancel = false;
                }
            }
```

Is there any other way to access the count in Javascript?

Regards,
Karthik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access a property of an object from Javascript either the property needs to be marked with the `ScriptableMember` attribute or the class to which it belongs is marked as `ScriptableType`.  Neither of these is true of the `ObservableCollection<T>` class.

A pragmatic solution would be to add a `HasChildren` property to your Custom object:-

```
 [ScriptableMember]
 public bool HasChildren
 {
      get { return Children.Count > 0; }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you made that observablecollection ScriptableMember? You need to add this attribute to make in available in javascript. Check the following link for more information:

[Walkthrough: Calling Managed Code from JavaScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221414%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

[HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.browser.htmlpage.registerscriptableobject%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

I hope it helps.

Comment: In order to access the Count property would that not also need to be a ScriptableMember as well?

Comment: Ya you're right @AnthonyWJones. In that case adding a property to the class, as you mentioned, is more appropriate. Thanks